# Android - MVP - Fragments, Presenter and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, mvp

I have an Activity1 that contains several fragments through a ViewPager.
Each fragment has a Presenter. For some reason when I rotate the screen, the fragment is recreated and lose the relationship with the presenter

I'm doing the following

1. open activity 1 (contains viewPager with fragment)
2. open activity 2
3. rotate the screen
4. Press back button

Apparently the fragment is recreated and I get the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   interface method 'void ....Presenter1.subscribe()' on a null object
>   reference at ....Fragment1.onResume(Fragment1.java:72)

My **Activity1 contains 2 views (layout and layout-normal-land)**
The code of activity1 is as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.htab_viewpager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_tabs);
    ...
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

the code of the ViewPagerAdapter class is the following:

```
private  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = Arrays.asList("Fragment1", "Fragment2");

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0){
            Fragment1 fragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
            new Presenter1(fragment);
            return fragment;

        }else if (position == 1){                
            Fragment2 fragment = Fragment2.newInstance();
            new Presenter2(fragment);
            return fragment;

        }
        return null;
    }

     @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentTitleList.size();
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

The code of each Fragment is the following

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mPresenter.subscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPresenter.unsubscribe();
    }


   @Override
   public void setPresenter(@NonNull Presenter1 presenter) {
        mPresenter = checkNotNull(presenter);
    }

    ....

}
```

The code of each presener

```
public class Presenter1 {

    private final Fragment1 view;

    public PerfilAlumnoCalificacionesPresenter(Fragment1 view ....) {
        ....
        this.view = view
        this.view.setPresenter(this);
    }

    ....

}
```

How can i fix this? I do not understand why the fragment is recreated if it contains setRetainInstance (true)

What is the best way to initialize the Presenter so that the Fragments do not lose the relation?

thanks, sorry for my english

Comment: This is a bug in android (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644080). This is officially fixed and will hopefully be rolled out soon...